# How to get DataSnapshot value to textview in outside of listener

Tags: java, android

I don't have much experience with Java. I need to get value from Firebase realtime database and return this value outside listener. I want to show that value in textview. I already get value from database.I want to show that value in "pre_units" textview. how to pass it outside listener? Here is my code.

```
    public class ShowUnits extends AppCompatActivity {


TextView textView_cus, cur_units, pre_units;

double Amount, Ser_Charge, Total_Amount, Before_VAT, Units, Test;

DatabaseReference databaseBills;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_units);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    databaseBills = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("bills");
    Query lastQuery = databaseBills.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
    lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String value = childSnapshot.child("current_units").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("onDataChange", "current_units=" + value);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    cur_units = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cur_units);
    pre_units = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pre_units);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    final double con = i.getDoubleExtra("Value", 0.0);
    cur_units.setText("" + con);
```

Comment: Make a screenshot of database structure, part from which you want to return values?

Comment: I was already turn value from database. I want return DataSnapshot value as a result of a method?